# Comparing $2^{317}$ and $81^{50}$ by hand

Tags: inequality, summation, logarithms, taylor-expansion, number-comparison

How to compare these two numbers without calculator:

$2^{317}$ and $81^{50}$

(Pen & paper test)

I thought about using logarithms and doing Taylor approximation, but these numbers are close to one another and I'd need a lot of Taylor expansion summands which defeats the purpose as raising 3 to some power of 15 and operating those fractions is not something you'd do by hand.

I've seen similar [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618786/compare-22016-and-10605-without-a-calculator) but there the powers were "nice" and are possible to simplify / reduce, yet there I don't see such an opportunity.

Comment: Yes, $2^{317}$ is bigger, but the quotient is only about $1.005212$. Perhaps it's good that we have a computer.

Comment: Perhaps as a start, we show that $2^{31}<81^5<2^{32}$.

Comment: Insufficient side note: the fact that $81^3$ is only 1% larger than $2^{19}$ is related to the fact that $(\frac32)^{12}$ is very close to $2^7$, which is the mathematical reason why we have the [circle of fifths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_fifths) in music (twelve perfect fifths is approximately seven octaves).

Comment: Note that $317/50$ is one of the continued-fraction approximants for $\frac{\log 81}{\log 2}$, so in a sense the exponents have been chosen for maximal difficulty of comparison.

Comment: People like me who were at school in the 1960s had base 10 logarithms burned into our brains, so I would have used $log_{10}2=0.30103$ and $log_{10}3=0.47712$ to calculate $317*0.30103 - 200*0.47712 \gt 0$. It's noteworthy that the 5 figure logs are needed, as the 4 figure logs give the wrong answer:  $317*0.3010 - 200*0.4771 \lt 0$

Comment: @ArthurVause I went to school a bit after you, but I found Voellmy's *Fünfstellige Logarithmen und Zahlentafeln* on my Dad's bookshelf :-) Because this is a close call you also need to estimate the rounding error. I'm sure you did, just making the remark for the benefit of the younger readers.

Comment: I observe, that $ 3^{200}  \overset?\le 2^{317}$ can be rewritten by $243^{40} \overset?\le 256^{40}/8$ then $8 \overset?\le (1+13/243)^{40}$ and then $2 \overset?\le (1+13/243)^{13}(1+13/243)$. From here possibly trying the first few terms of the binomial expansion in the rhs - but somehow still doesn't look much promising ... :-( and I give up ...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms problem is that $(1+\frac{13}{243})^{39} < 8$ and $(1+\frac{13}{243})^{40} > 8$ so we can't just drop one power less and then divide it by 3 (so to take cube root from both sides)

Comment: @AlmaDo - ahh, yes, that is a bug in my idea... sorry.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I've followed a similar path before and attempted to half $40$ as much as I can. Arrived to this: $(1+\frac{13}{243})^{40} > (1+\frac{376}{{3}^{6}})^{5} = (1+\frac{{2}^{3}*47}{{3}^{6}})^{5}> 8$ but it's still not something I can do a binomial expansion on

Comment: *(Pen & paper test)* --- Can you be a bit more specific? Knowing the test and what we're allowed to assume (e.g. random approximations such as $\sqrt 3 \approx 1.732,$ binomial expansions, derivatives and Taylor's theorem, etc.) and the approximate amount of time a test taker is ordinarily expected to take are extremely important things to know when seeing something like this with no context to guide us. (It always puzzles me why so often problems like this are posted with no citation. I makes me a bit suspicious as to whether the OP is allowed to ask this on the internet.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro to be honest, at this point I'm wondering how it's possible to do at all, regardless of methods (so long as it's doable with pen and paper within the reasonable effort). But if you're interested - I was asked about this for the test that happens at 7th grade of the primary school (Russia), though the school is with "math focus". The age would be 12-13 y.o. children and the test has about 10 questions and lasts for 120 minutes.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I humbly recommend you to stop assuming something that's not there. You can just check my network profile to understand that I'm waaaay past my school years. It'd be nice to be back there, yes - yet alas, I'm not the one undertaking such test. Can I do a "citation"? I cannot, it was referred to me on a hearsay with the mention on what grade the test is and roughly what school profile is. I know neither the source nor the specific location. I tried it myself and didn't solve it. Hence asked here.

Comment: (+1) Regardless of where this showed up, it appears to have generated a fair amount of interest here. You may want add to your question by including what you've said in comments about the origin of the problem.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I've double-checked the question after your comment and it seems I got it wrong (well, hearsay and whatnot). Original question seems to be far worse - it goes like this: "Find the smallest natural number *n* such that ${2}^{n} > {81}^{50}$" (with the answer 317 obviously). But oh well, I'll leave this as it is, it's too late at this point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$
2^{317} > 81^{50} \iff 2^{17} > \left(\frac98\right)^{100} \iff \log_e2 > \frac{100}{17}\log_e\frac98,
$$
and
$$
\log_e2 = \log_e\frac{1 + 1/3}{1 - 1/3} > 2\left(\frac13 + \frac1{3\cdot3^3} + \frac1{5\cdot3^5}\right) = \frac23\left(1 + \frac1{27} + \frac1{405}\right) = \frac{842}{1215},
$$
and
\begin{gather*}
\frac{100}{17}\log_e\frac98 = \frac{100}{17}\log_e\frac{1 + 1/17}{1 - 1/17} = \frac{200}{17^2}\left(1 + \frac1{3\cdot17^2} + \frac1{5\cdot17^4} + \cdots\right) \\
< \frac{200}{17^2}\left(1 + \frac1{3\cdot17^2}\left(1 + \frac1{17} + \frac1{17^2} + \cdots\right)\right) = \frac{200}{17^2}\left(1 + \frac1{3\cdot16\cdot17}\right) \\ = \frac{200\cdot817}{3\cdot16\cdot17^3}
= \frac{25\cdot817}{6\cdot4913} = \frac{25\cdot817}{29478} < \frac{25\cdot817}{29475} = \frac{817}{1179},
\end{gather*}
and
$$
842\cdot1179 = 992718 > 992655 = 1215\cdot817,
$$
therefore
$$
\log_e2 > \frac{842}{1215} > \frac{817}{1179} > \frac{100}{17}\log_e\frac98,
$$
therefore
$$
2^{317} > 81^{50}.
$$

Comment: (+1) I've only checked about a third of the details (all correct that I can tell), but assuming everything is correct, this is the only answer (thus far) that I would guess qualifies as an appropriate method. However, it's difficult for me to imagine this as something one would expect even [1 in 10,000 12-13 year olds could do](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254834/comparing-2317-and-8150-by-hand?noredirect=1#comment8847713_4254834). Nonetheless, I doubt a less advanced method (e.g. not requiring logarithm series expansions) exists that is not much more involved computationally.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro this seems about accurate (the number of kids to do it I mean). The aforementioned school is an establishment where they take "gifted children" with an entering contest competition, usually they gather it for the whole federal land and form a group (so it is indeed that only 1 in ~8000 goes into there if I count correctly)

Answer (score 2):

It is worth noting as in one of the comments that the standard estimates in base $10$ of $\log(2)\sim 0.3010$ and $\log(3)\sim 0.4771$ do not yield the correct answer.

To prove that $2^{317}>81^{50}=3^{200},$ the following is doable by hand:
$$2^{317}>3^{200}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2^{1.585}>3$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2^{0.585}>1.5$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2^{1.17}>2.25$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2^{0.17}>1.125$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \left(2^{0.17}\right)^6>1.125^6$$
$$\Leftarrow 2^{1.02}>1.42383^2~ (\because 1.125^3=1.423828125)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2^{1.02}>2.027291869$$
$$\Leftarrow 2^{0.02}>\frac{2.027292}2=1.013646$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2^2>1.013646^{100}$$
$$\Leftarrow 2^2>1.0137^{100}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2>1.0137^{50}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2>1.02758769^{25}$$
$$\Leftarrow 2>1.028^{25}$$
$$\Leftarrow 2>1.1481^5,$$ where one uses $1.028^2=1.056784$ and $1.028^3=1.086373952$ and hence $1.028^5$ is bounded by $1.05679\times 1.08638=1.14807552.$  The arrows of implications continue as follows
$$\Leftarrow 2> (1.15)(1.1481^4)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac {40}{23}>1.1481^4$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac {40}{23}>1.31813361^2$$
$$\Leftarrow \frac {40}{23} > 1.3182^2,$$ which is true, since $$1.7391\cdots > 1.73765124.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not exactly easy to use approximations in this case, as both numbers are extremely close. Instead, just calculate each number with square and multiply:
$$ 2^{317}=2\cdot 2^{316}=2\cdot 16^{79} = 32\cdot 16^{78} = 32\cdot 256^{39} = 8192 \cdot 65536^{19} = 536870912\cdot 4294967296^9 = 2305843009213693952\cdot 4294967296^8 = 2305843009213693952\cdot 18446744073709551616^4 = 2305843009213693952\cdot 340282366920938463463374607431768211456^2 = 2305843009213693952\cdot 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936 = 266998379490113760299377713271194014325338065294581596243380200977777465722580068752870260867072$$
Similarly
$$ 81^{50} = 6561^{25} = 6561 \cdot43046721^{12} = 6561 \cdot 1853020188851841^6 = 6561 \cdot 3433683820292512484657849089281^3 = 22528399544939174411840147874772641 \cdot 11790184577738583171520872861412518665678211592275841109096961 = 265613988875874769338781322035779626829233452653394495974574961739092490901302182994384699044001$$

By writing the results under each other

$\begin{align*}
266998379490113760299377713271194014325338065294581596243380200977777465722580068752870260867072& \\
265613988875874769338781322035779626829233452653394495974574961739092490901302182994384699044001&
\end{align*}$

we see that the results are of same length and the third digit differs, making $2^{317}$ larger than $81^{50}$

Comment: (+1) but did you really do this by hand?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Of course i did not calculate these steps by hand, because there is no particular reason to do so (it just increases the time needed to reply). But each of these multiplications is quite doable by hand.

Comment: Well, Lazy - I'm just sure, that ocean of digits would have a lot of numerical errors if I did this by hand, in such an amount that I do not know, whether I were able to evaluate this even in a week. But I'm sceptical of myself - perhaps this unability is only due to the yearlong missing training in such explicte calculations by hand, or simply due to aging - and for some energetic young people (which I've been myself years ago) it would be doable in an hour, or in a day ... No criticism has been intended!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms It’s not that much, it just looks badly here. The factor with the most digits has somewhat 78 digits, I believe. And if you bound the relative error it does not matter that much if you have slight mistakes.

But these calculations should be doable in 10 minutes at most.

Answer (score 1):

***This is not an answer, but too long for a comment-box***

An option to work with the logarithms is possibly, to use the Mercator-series for $\log(1+x)$ which is well known and "handy" and can be used in this way: $$\small \log(1+x/2)-\log(1-x/2) \small = x + 1/12x^3 + 1/80x^5 + 1/448x^7 + 1/2304x^9 + 1/11264x^{11} + 1/53248x^{13} + O(x^{15}) $$ and assigning $x=1$ for the approximation-series of $\log(3)$:
$$ \log(3) = 1+ 1/12 + 1/80 + 1/448 + 1/2304 + 1/11264 + ... \tag 1 $$
The explicite terms of this approximation-series can be found by hand to some leading terms.

Similarly from $\small \log(2)=\log(1+1/3)-\log(1-1/3)$ one can get
$$ \log(2) = 2/3 + 2/81 + 2/1215 + 2/15309 + 2/177147 + 2/1948617 + 2/20726199 + ... \tag 2$$
Now we can write the subtraction $$ \Lambda_n = 317 \cdot P(\log(2),n) - 200 \cdot P(\log(3),n) \tag 3$$ for $n=1$ to some index, where $P(\log(2),n)$ means the partial series of first $n$ terms of the logarithmic approximation-series for the argument.

This is just to record the idea, I didn't do this by hand towards the solution. Using Pari/GP the termwise differences for $n=1 .. 16$ are anyway

```
                                          34/3
                                       -716/81
                                    -4807/2430
                                 -49603/122472
                               -471787/5668704
                            -4347523/249422976
                         -39533467/10611813888
                       -357424243/440798423040
                      -189606491/1057916215296
                  -29035761763/723614691262464
               -261425730427/28792247715495936
            -2353247072083/1135237195639554048
          -21180885641707/44422325046765158400
       -190634618747203/1727139997818229358592
     -1715738160612187/66782746582304868532224
  -15441749813059123/2569984316753525285584896
 ...
```

It remains to show, that the partial summation of this terms from `34/3` minus `716/81` and so on stays positive.
I don't know whether this is doable with any reasonable effort; it seems to be difficult anyway, when one looks at the sequence of partial sum in decimal representation:

```
     11.33333333
     2.493827160
    0.5156378601
    0.1106228362
   0.02739622924
  0.009965906383
  0.006240486071
  0.005429629625
  0.005250403247
  0.005210277249
  0.005201197523
  0.005199124611
  0.005198647803
  0.005198537427
  0.005198511736
  0.005198505728
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I (think) I found a solution that does not involve doing natural logarithms / logarithms at all and relies on basic algebra + approximation.

First step: multiply/divide ${2}^{317}$ by 8 and expand $81={3}^{4}$ we will have:

$$\frac{{2}^{320}}{8}\space?\space{3}^{200}$$

Next we can take the 40th root from both sides to arrive at this:

$$\frac{2^8}{3^5}\space?\space\sqrt[40]{8}$$

Or in other words:

$${(1+\frac{13}{243})}^{40}\space?\space8$$

So here we will reduce the powers very carefully by expanding the binomial as a square one step at a time and then replacing some of the numbers with those which are close to the power of 3. Here's how I do this:

$${(1+\frac{13}{243})}^{40} = {(1+\frac{2\cdot13}{3^5}+\frac{169}{3^{10}})}^{20} > {(1+\frac{2\cdot13}{3^5}+\frac{162}{3^{10}})}^{20} = {(1+\frac{2\cdot13}{3^5}+\frac{2\cdot3^4}{3^{10}})}^{20}$$
$$={(1+\frac{2\cdot13}{3^5}+\frac{2}{3^6})}^{20} = {(1+\frac{2\cdot3\cdot13+2}{3^6})}^{20}= {(1+\frac{80}{3^6})}^{20}$$

And we've successfully reduced the power by half while still retaining the manageable numbers under the calculation. So, next step:

$${(1+\frac{80}{3^6})}^{20}={(1+\frac{2\cdot80}{3^6}+\frac{6400}{3^{12}})}^{10}>{(1+\frac{2\cdot80}{3^6}+\frac{6399}{3^{12}})}^{10}={(1+\frac{2\cdot80}{3^6}+\frac{79\cdot3^4}{3^{12}})}^{10}$$
$$={(1+\frac{2\cdot80}{3^6}+\frac{79}{3^8})}^{10}={(1+\frac{160\cdot3^2+79}{3^8})}^{10}={(1+\frac{1519}{3^8})}^{10}>{(1+\frac{1518}{3^8})}^{10}={(1+\frac{3\cdot506}{3^8})}^{10}
={(1+\frac{506}{3^7})}^{10}$$

So we did halve it again and the numbers are still doable. Next step involves calculating $506^2$ but I assume one time is fine and it's a three-digit number close to 500, so I did it as $506^2=(500+6)^2=500^2+12\cdot500+36$.

Another tricky part in this step is finding out that $256036>255879$ i.e. choosing that "magic" number. Here's the algorithm I employ here (basically this is how I found these numbers for all steps):

1. Divide the original number by 3 with a remainder, check what that remainder is
2. Divide it again by 3 and continue to do so until we're down to the number less than 3. Note down the remainders on each step.
3. Compare the remainders. The smallest one will signify which power of 3 we want to choose. And of course the division result on that step is our second factor ($13$ in the case below)
4. For the division by 3 I use the "fast division" that's excellently described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xwcub1rf3pY).

Anyways,back to our inequality:

$${(1+\frac{506}{3^7})}^{10}={(1+\frac{2\cdot506}{3^7}+\frac{256036}{3^{14}})}^{5}>{(1+\frac{2\cdot506}{3^7}+\frac{255879}{3^{14}})}^{5}={(1+\frac{2\cdot506}{3^7}+\frac{13\cdot3^9}{3^{14}})}^{5}$$
$$={(1+\frac{2\cdot506}{3^7}+\frac{13}{3^{5}})}^{5}={(1+\frac{2\cdot506+13\cdot3^2}{3^7})}^{5}={(1+\frac{1129}{3^7})}^{5}={(\frac{3316}{3^7})}^{5}$$

And we've completed the power halving. Next step is - we want to estimate $\sqrt[5]{8}$ and to do so we can notice that ${(\frac{3}{2})}^5\approx8$ but still pretty close which makes it a good guess. We can "notice" this since $8-(\frac{3}{2})^5=8-\frac{243}{32}=\frac{13}{256}$ (close to $0$).

Here's what Newton's method gives. Suppose we have $x_{0}=\frac{3}{2}$ (we chose that guess earlier, see above). Then:

$$x_{1} = \frac{4}{5}\cdot x_0 + \frac{8}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{{x_0}^{4}}=\frac{4}{5}\cdot(\frac{3}{2}+2\cdot{(\frac{2}{3})}^4)=\frac{614}{405}=\frac{2\cdot307}{5\cdot3^4}>\sqrt[5]{8}$$

Critical bit here is that $x_{1}>\sqrt[5]{8}$. We can indeed claim it because we're approximating $f(x)=x^5-8$ and geometrically we are setting the tangent line to the $f(x)$ at the point $x_0=\frac{3}{2}$ which will then intersect the $x$-axis at $x_{1}$: but $f(x)$ is convex down for all $x>0$ therefore our tangent line at $x_0$ can never cross the graph of $f(x)$ to the right of our $x_0$. That means that it will cross the $x$-axis below the graph of $f(x)$ meaning that $x_1$ will be to the right of the true root which is $\sqrt[5]{8}$ and hence $x_{1}>\sqrt[5]{8}$

All that's left is to compare our $x_1$ with the fraction we've built before:

$$\frac{3316}{3^7}=\frac{2^2\cdot829}{3^7}\space?\space\frac{2\cdot307}{5\cdot3^4}$$

Removing common terms:

$$\frac{2\cdot829}{27}\space?\space\frac{307}{5}$$
$$10\cdot829\space?\space27\cdot307$$
$$8290>8289$$

(By the way,a difference of 1 is as close as it can possibly be which I find hilarious) So we managed to build this:

$${(1+\frac{13}{243})}^{40}>{(1+\frac{80}{3^6})}^{20}>{(1+\frac{506}{3^7})}^{10}>{(\frac{3316}{3^7})}^{5}>(\frac{614}{405})^{5}>8$$

Hence $\frac{2^8}{3^5}>\sqrt[40]{8}$ and finally

$${2}^{317}>{3}^{200}={81}^{50}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Alternative solution*:

We have
$$2^{317} > 81^{50} ~ \iff ~ 2^{317\cdot 3/50} > 81^3
~ \iff ~
2^{1/50}2^{19} > 81^3$$
$$~ \Leftarrow ~ \left(1 + \frac{1}{50}\ln 2\right)2^{19} > 81^3 ~ \Leftarrow ~ \left(1 + \frac{1}{50}\cdot \frac{11}{16}\right)2^{19} > 81^3$$
$$~ \iff ~ 811 \cdot 2^{16} > 81^3 \cdot 100
~ \iff ~ (10 + 1/81)\cdot 2^{16} > 81^2 \cdot 100$$
$$ ~ \iff ~ \frac{1}{81}\cdot 2^{16}
> 81^2 \cdot 100 - 10 \cdot 2^{16}$$
$$
~ \iff ~ \frac{1}{81}\cdot 65536
> 6561 \cdot 100 - 10 \cdot 65536 = 740$$
$$~ \iff ~ 65536 > 81 \cdot 740$$
which is true; here, we have used $\mathrm{e}^{y} \ge 1 + y$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\ln 2 > \frac{11}{16}$ which follows from (I learned it from @Jack D'Aurizio)
$$0 < \int_0^1 \frac{x^2(1 - x)^2}{1 + x}\,\mathrm{d} x = \int_0^1
\left(x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x - 4 + \frac{4}{1 + x}\right)\mathrm{d} x = 4\ln 2 - \frac{11}{4}.$$

Comment: (+1) Much less laborious than mine.  Easier than the last line is:
$$
\log_e2 > 2\left(\frac13 + \frac1{3\cdot3^3}\right) = \frac{56}{81}
> \frac{55}{80} = \frac{11}{16}.
$$

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Thanks. Your solution is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is something you consider as 'by hand', but the only thing you really need to calculate to a couple decimals is $2^{1.585}$.

We want to know the ratio $r = \frac{2^{317}}{3^{200}}$. Taking logarithms on both sides $$
\ln r = \ln\left(\frac{2^{317}}{3^{200}}\right) = 317 \ln 2 - 200 \ln 3.$$

Note that $317/200 = 1.585$ and we have that $2^{1.585}$ is slightly bigger than $3$. So in fact we have a lower bound for $\ln r$, hence the ratio by $$
\ln r = 317 \ln 2 - 200 \ln 3 >  317 \ln 2 - 200 \ln 2^{1.585} = 317 \ln 2 - 317 \ln 2 = 0,
$$

so $r > e^0 = 1$, hence $2^{317}$ is slightly bigger.

Comment: $2^{1.585}\approx 3.000078$, so not really just "a couple" decimals.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand how I can get ${2}^{1.585}$ by hand in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps not completely satisfactory but you can write $2^{1.585}$ as $2\sqrt{2} \cdot 2^{0.085}$. By computing $2 \sqrt{2}$ to $5$ decimals by hand we find that to show $2^{1.585} > 3$ it is enough to show $2^{0.085} > 1.06066$. Then using $\ln 2 > 0.693$ you can compute 4 terms of the series for $e^x$ for $x = 0.693 \cdot 0.085$ and you have that $2^{0.085} = e^{0.085 \cdot \ln 2} > e^{0.085 \cdot 0.693} >1.06067$. I don't think it is really slick, but these calculations are doable by hand (although, it might take half an hour or so) and it only assumes we know $\ln 2$ to $3$ decimal places.

Comment: I don't understand how do I "compute root 8 to 5 decimals" by hand?

Comment: You can use a digit-by-digit calculation method, for example the one given on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation). It's been a while since I last computed square roots by hand but from what I recall it's not too much effort.

Comment: Typo: I believe in the last displayed equality/inequality chain, $200 \ln 2 - 200 \ln 2^{1.585}$ should be $317 \ln 2 - 200 \ln 2^{1.585}.$